# How to release(ARC) the CoreFoundation object when the method returns CFObject?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have the CFObject returning method similar to below

```
-(CFMutableAttributedStringRef)getAttStrForArray:(NSArray*)substrings forString:(NSString*)aStr
{

   CFMutableAttributedStringRef as3 = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
    CFAttributedStringBeginEditing(as3);
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("HelveticaNeue-Bold"), 12.5, NULL);
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString(as3, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (__bridge CFStringRef)aStr);
   ......
   CFAttributedStringEndEditing(as3);
    //CFRelease(as3);
   return as3;

}
```

here i'm getting memory leak that i hav't released the `CFRelease(as3);` object since it's a return method. is there any way to fix the memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, `NSAttributedString` and `NSMutableAttributedString` are both toll-free bridged to their Core Foundation counterparts `CFAttributedStringRef` and `CFMutableAttributedStringRef` respectively. That means you can create, for example, a `CFAttributedStringRef` and simply cast it to an `NSAttributedString` pointer, and then calling `NSAttributedString` methods on it will work.

so just bridge cast it to the arc

`NSAttributedString *nsString = (__bridge transfer NSAttributedString*)as3`

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)getAttStrForArray:(NSArray*)substrings forString:(NSString*)aStr
{
   CFMutableAttributedStringRef as3 = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
   //...
   return (__bridge transfer NSAttributedString*)as3;
}
```

Comment: i did like this ` NSAttributedString *nsString = (__bridge_transfer NSAttributedString*)as3;
   // CFRelease(as3);
    return (__bridge  CFMutableAttributedStringRef)nsString;
` but throws error on 'CFAttributedStringCreateCopy(NULL, as2) : NULL;'